# Visual Studio Installer project always installing .NET Framework 4.8 prerequisite even if already installed

Tags: visual-studio, setup-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my windows forms application via Visual Studio Installer extension.

As shown below, I'm setting .NET Framework 4.8 as a one-and-only prerequisite.

[image: Visual Studio Installer Setup Prerequisite]

The problem is, when I test the installer package on target computer, the setup installs the .NET Framework 4.8 properly at first time which is good but after I un-installed my application and re-run the installer, the setup project again starting to install .NET Framework 4.8 while it's already installed.

It seems like the installer does not check if the prerequisite already installed which is annoying behaviour. Is there a way to fix or prevent this?

Comment: I bet the check for installed 4.8 is done by the packaged 4.8 installer and not YOUR installer.  There is a reason that quick and simple installers don't produce what most people want.  If you want this level of finite control, you will probably need to move to a system like WIX where you have more finite control of the produced MSI (but there is a learning curve).  ***I hope someone else here gives you a better answer*** but I have written setups since the invention of MSI and I doubt it.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas-ReinstateMonica As far as I've read about the Visual Studio Installer extension, it's the setup file (setup.exe) which controls and manages the prerequisites before the .MSI is run. MSI itself actually has nothing to do with prerequisites, it's the reason for setup.exe is created, which is why I thought there could be a fix.

Comment: @RoniTovi did you get any solution for this? I am facing the same issue.